# Получить данные через Types в процедуре

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть два типа:

```
create or replace 
  type CASES_TYPE_N IS object(
    CASEID VARCHAR2(128),
    FirstNumber VARCHAR2(32),
    DLR number
  );

create or replace 
TYPE CASES_TABLE_N AS TABLE OF CASES_TYPE_N;
```

Есть Package:

```
create or replace 
PACKAGE BANKRUPT_TEST AS 
  procedure BANKRUPT_TEST_p(
                           pType            in integer,
                           pRequestDate     in varchar2,
                           CasesList_1      out CASES_TABLE_N,
                           ResultCode       out integer,
                           ErrorText        out varchar2);

END BANKRUPT_TEST;
```

И его тело:

```
 create or replace
    PACKAGE BODY BANKRUPT_TEST AS
      procedure BANKRUPT_TEST_p(
                               pType            in integer,
                               pRequestDate     in varchar2,
                               CasesList_1      out CASES_TABLE_N,
                               ResultCode       out integer,
                               ErrorText        out varchar2) AS
      BEGIN 
        ResultCode := pType;
        ErrorText  := pRequestDate;

        select CASES_TYPE_N(CaseID, FirstNumber, dlr) 
        bulk   collect into CasesList_1
        from   ( 
                 select 'CaseID' as CaseID,
                        'Fnum' as FirstNumber,
                        15 as dlr 
                 from   dual);

        NULL;

      END BANKRUPT_TEST_p;

    END BANKRUPT_TEST;
```

Все это запускается в Oracle SQL Developer.
После запуска я получаю только переменные `ResultCode` и `ErrorText`.
А нужно получить еще и данные из `CasesList_1`. Как их правильно получить?

Исторически сложилось, что нужно сделать через Types, а не через, например, курсоры.

Comment: А в чем собственно проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CasesList_1` вы должны получить там же, где и две другие упомянутые переменные.

Вызываем:

```
declare  
    cases cases_table_n;
    rc integer;
    errmsg varchar2(128);
begin
    bankrupt_test.bankrupt_test_p(1, to_char(sysdate), cases, rc, errmsg);
    for idx in 1..cases.last loop
        dbms_output.put_line('case '||cases(idx).caseid||'/'||cases(idx).firstnumber||'/'||cases(idx).dlr);
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Получаем:

```
case CaseID/Fnum/15
```

Или добавте в спецификацию и тело пакета функцию возвращающую результат:

```
function getcases return cases_table_n is
    cases cases_table_n;
    rc integer;
    errmsg varchar2(128);
begin 
    bankrupt_test.bankrupt_test_p(1, to_char(sysdate), cases, rc, errmsg);
    return cases;
end;

col caseid for a20
select * from table(bankrupt_test.getCases());  

CASEID               FIRSTNUMBER                             DLR
-------------------- -------------------------------- ----------
CaseID               Fnum                                     15
```

UPD: Или заменить на функцию для инициализации и возврата данных где-то так:

```
create or replace function bankrupt_test_p1(
    pRequestDate in varchar2,
    ResultCode  out integer,
    ErrorText   out varchar2
    ) return cases_table_n is
    ret cases_table_n
begin
    select cases_type_n(distinct CaseID, FirstNumber, DLR)
    bulk collect into ret
    from aa_table 
    where DownloadDate = pRequestDate 
    and ClientID is not null
    ;
    ResultCode := 0;
    ErrorText  := pRequestDate||': found '||ret.count||' rows';
    return ret;

exception when others then
    ResultCode := -1;
    ErrorText  := pRequestDate||': fatal: '||sqlerrm;
end bankrupt_test_p1;
```

Comment: Спасибо!
Заработало.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за помощь!
Применил к своим Types, получилось так:

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY BANKRUPT_TEST1 AS

  procedure BANKRUPT_TEST_p1(
                           pType            in integer,
                           pRequestDate     in varchar2,
                           CasesList_1      out CASES_TABLE_N,
                           ResultCode       out integer,
                           ErrorText        out varchar2) IS
    nCur            number;

  BEGIN
    ResultCode := pType;
    ErrorText  := pRequestDate;

    begin
       CasesList_1:=CASES_TABLE_N();
    exception 
      when others then null;
    end;

    for rec in(        
      select distinct CaseID,
             FirstNumber,
             DLR
      from   AA_TABLE
      where  DownloadDate = pRequestDate 
      and    ClientID is not null
    ) 
    loop
      CasesList_1.extend;
      nCur := CasesList_1.last;
      CasesList_1(nCur) := CASES_TYPE_N(null, null, null);

      begin
        CasesList_1(nCur).CASEID := rec.caseid;
      exception 
        when others then null;
      end;

      begin
        CasesList_1(nCur).FirstNumber := rec.firstnumber;
      exception 
        when others then null;
      end;

      begin
        CasesList_1(nCur).DLR := rec.dlr;
        exception 
          when others then null;
        end;

    end loop; 

    NULL;
  END BANKRUPT_TEST_p1;
END BANKRUPT_TEST1;
```

Comment: Я не уверен, что это оптимальное решение. CasesList был инициализирован с bulk collect теперь в цикле. Зачем?   Что всё-таки нужно получить. в итоге?

Comment: В итоге данные из CasesList_1 нужно передать в шину и сформировать XML. Но это уже не на моей стороне.

Comment: Это "получилось" даже не скомпилируется и кроме того, в каждой строчке можно ставить знак вопроса. Посмотрите - я добавил ещё пример.

Comment: Да, проблема копипаста. Поправил свой код.
Заменить на функцию не получится по административным причинам. Если бы не эти самые причины, был бы просто dblink.